# Cannot open Servicename service on computer '.'. Error on Starting Windows Service programatically using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-services

I have made a Windows Service and installed it on my system.Now as per my requirement i have to start and stop this windows Service using Button click from Windows Form Application.
Here is my Code ..

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string svcStatus;
    ServiceController myService;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myService = new ServiceController();
        myService.ServiceName = "ServiceName";
        svcStatus = myService.Status.ToString();
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (svcStatus == "Stopped")
        {
            myService.Start();   // START the service if it is already Stopped

            string svcStatusWas = "";  
            while (svcStatus != "Running")
            {
                if (svcStatus != svcStatusWas)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Status: " + svcStatus);
                }

                svcStatusWas = svcStatus;

                myService.Refresh();
                svcStatus = myService.Status.ToString();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Service Started!!");
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (svcStatus == "Running")
        {                
            myService.Stop();   // STOP the service if it is already Running

            string svcStatusWas = "";   
            while (svcStatus != "Stopped")
            {

                svcStatusWas = svcStatus;

                myService.Refresh();    
                svcStatus = myService.Status.ToString();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Service Stopped!!");
        }
    }     
}
```

}

I am getting error "Cannot open Servicename service on computer '.'." at this line myService.Start();

Please help me.

Comment: Is the service you are trying to start really called "ServiceName"?

Comment: Is the service present on the machine? Are you sure you're using the *service name*, not the service executable's *file name*?

Comment: Do you have permission to start/stop services under the user you're running as?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not an issue if you are running on an XP machine or under the debugger of Visual Studios, but only when you deploy your program on a Windows 7 machine you see the error:

> Cannot open < servicename > service on computer '.'.

This is most likely because of the privileges change which occurred since Vista regarding the User Account Control.

You can validate that this is indeed what is causing the issue if you try running the application as administrator and the issue does not occur.

**In order to Start or Stop a Windows services you need to run your C# program with administration rights.**

This can either be done manually, by right clicking on the application and then click 'Run as administrator'

Or this can be done programmatically by setting your program to always run with administration right if you add the below code in your app.manifest file located in the Properties folder in your project in Solution Explorer:

```
 <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app" />
 <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
 <security>
 <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
 <!-- UAC Manifest Options
  If you want to change the Windows User Account Control level replace the 
  requestedExecutionLevel node with one of the following.

 <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />

  If you want to utilize File and Registry Virtualization for backward 
  compatibility then delete the requestedExecutionLevel node.
 -->
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
 </requestedPrivileges>
 <applicationRequestMinimum>
 <defaultAssemblyRequest permissionSetReference="Custom" />
 <PermissionSet class="System.Security.PermissionSet" version="1" Unrestricted="true" ID="Custom" SameSite="site" />
 </applicationRequestMinimum>
 </security>
 </trustInfo>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

You can find more info on Creating and Embedding an Application Manifest (UAC) here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Pranav, you need to run your application with Administrator privileges. If you run Visual Studio as an administrator, your application should work correctly in debug mode.

When you come to deploy your application, you can either run it in administrator mode by default, or assign the appropriate privileges to your application to enable it to start and stop particular services (I believe this is done on the command line). I have done this a while ago, and a quick Google search will help you.